# Solr ignoring NOT but works with "-" and "!"

Tags: search

I have a apachesolr module which works well except in one case. I'm not sure what happens when `NOT` is entered in query, it behaves as `OR`. It even works for `!` and `-` case.

For eg.

```
"apple" -"orange" //Results that only has "apple" but not "orange"
"apple" NOT "orange" //Results all the entities that has either "apple" or "oranges"
```

I have the a very similar installation on another site which seems to work without flaw. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with my implementation. Before the query was posted to Solr, I was doing following:

```
$query = strtolower($query);
```

This made the `NOT` to `not` hence it wasn't working as expected.